# How to analyze combined data from studies with overlap in subjects?

Tags: regression, crossover-study, overlapping-data

I have data from multiple placebo-controlled cross-over trials (each with $n \simeq 20$) with unique phenotypes measured during the placebo phase. I'd like to combine the data from these measurements from the different studies (i.e. make a bigger cohort composed of individuals who participated in placebo-phase of cross-over trials) to see if specific phenotypes are associated with each other (e.g. with multivariable regression, also adjusting for study). However, there are some subjects who participated in multiple trials (sometimes up to 3-4 trials).

How can I take this overlap in subjects between studies into account in the data analysis? Would it be necessary to include data from each subject only once (e.g. take data for each subject from study which contributed the most data relevant of my phenotypes of interest)?

Comment: You probably can't cherry-pick data that just makes your results look nice...

Comment: I'm aware of the issue of cherry-picking, so the choice for study would be based purely on number of phenotypes available in study (as not all studies measured same phenotypes) before looking into data at all. Obviously I'd prefer to include all data anyway, so any advice would be very welcome.